# Oracle 11g XE - Using a stored procedure to grant privileges to a table

Tags: oracle, permissions

I need to write a stored procedure that will grant certain privileges over a table to a user.

However it appears that GRANT cannot be used within a Stored Procedure.

My Curent code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE "setUserPermissions" (u  VARCHAR2, l  INTEGER, tbl VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM "userLvl" WHERE "user" = u;
    INSERT INTO "userLvl" VALUES(u,l);
    IF l>0 AND l<6 THEN
        GRANT SELECT ON tbl TO u
        IF l>1 THEN
            GRANT UPDATE ON tbl TO u
        END IF;
        IF l>2 THEN
             GRANT DELETE ON tbl TO u
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What is the error message when you run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GRANT` is a DDL statement. You can not run DDL statements directly in PL/SQL, but you can use execute immediate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE "setUserPermissions" (u  VARCHAR2, l  INTEGER, tbl VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM "userLvl" WHERE "user" = u;
    INSERT INTO "userLvl" VALUES(u,l);
    IF l>0 AND l<6 THEN
        execute immediate 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || tbl || ' TO ' || u;
        ...
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It does go without errors now. However my procedure does not have privileges to grant permissions to users. Do you know how I give the permissions to it?

Comment: @Vinicius Zolin De Jesus I can not see any schema spec. in your grant code, so you grant privileges on objects in your own schema, and that does not require any privileges. However, if you have synonyms in your schema that point to objects in other schemas, and you try to grant privileges using those synonyms, you need to be granted the privileges directly to your user with grant option, otherwise you can not grant them further, and you will recive an `ORA-01031` error. Another option is to have the `GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE` privilege granted to your user directly (not through a role).

Comment: Same goes for views, if they refer tables in another schemas.

Comment: I'm running it with the SYS user. It has enough privileges.